# Kannel sending unwanted "extra SMS"

Tags: kannel

Got Kannel working on Ubuntu12.10 and it can send and receive SMS. Issue is, after every SMS it sends or receives, it sends along an extra SMS with the content being `Live SMS Live SMS` which is actually the name of my ASP.Net development sever based application.

When I run my ASP application, it shows a web page title of "Live SMS" and one line content of  "Live SMS".

Am using [Port Forwarding For Windows](http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php) to be able to access the development server URL from another machine.

Below is my Kannel Log and below that is my Kannel.conf file.

**Kannel Log**

```
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [4] INFO: Starting to service <U KJF2111G> from <+1826909535> to <1926909539>
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [4] DEBUG: Started thread 8 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [4] DEBUG: Started thread 9 (gwlib/http.c:write_request_thread)
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG: Thread 9 (gwlib/http.c:write_request_thread) maps to pid 22228.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG: Queue contains 0 pending requests.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG: Parsing URL `http://192.168.152.1:8080/ProjRequestProcessor/ReceiveSMS.aspx?text=U+KJF2111G&sender1=%2B1826909535':
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Scheme: http://
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Host: 192.168.152.1
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Port: 8080
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Username: (null)
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Password: (null)
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Path: /ProjRequestProcessor/ReceiveSMS.aspx
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Query: text=U+KJF2111G&sender1=%2B1826909535
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG:   Fragment: (null)
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: Thread 8 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 22228.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG: HTTP: Opening connection to `192.168.152.1:8080' (fd=28).
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [9] DEBUG: Socket connecting
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: Get info about connecting socket
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: HTTP: Sending request:
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: Octet string at 0x7ff9280008e0:
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   len:  171
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   size: 1024
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   immutable: 0
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 47 45 54 20 2f 55 50 61 72 6b 52 65 71 75 65 73   GET /ProjReques
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 74 50 72 6f 63 65 73 73 6f 72 2f 52 65 63 65 69   tProcessor/Recei
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 76 65 53 4d 53 2e 61 73 70 78 3f 74 65 78 74 3d   veSMS.aspx?text=
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 55 2b 4b 4a 46 32 31 31 31 47 26 73 65 6e 64 65   U+KJF2111G&sende
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 72 31 3d 25 32 42 32 35 34 37 32 36 37 30 33 35   r1=%2B1826909535
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 33 35 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 48 6f 73   35 HTTP/1.1..Hos
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 74 3a 20 31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e 31 35 32 2e 31   t: 192.168.152.1
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 3a 38 30 38 30 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f   :8080..Connectio
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70 2d 61 6c 69 76 65 0d 0a 55   n: keep-alive..U
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 4b 61 6e 6e 65   ser-Agent: Kanne
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6c 2f 31 2e 34 2e 33 0d 0a 0d 0a                  l/1.4.3....
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: Octet string dump ends.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `192.168.152.1'.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7ff94c000a90.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] INFO: smsbox: Got HTTP request </cgi-bin/sendsms> from <192.168.152.1>
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] INFO: sendsms used by <kannel>
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] INFO: sendsms sender:<kannel:13013> (192.168.152.1) to:< 1826909535> msg:<UDA3HA4DK9 confirmed. We have recived your SMS

Thank you for working with Proj.>
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] DEBUG: Stored UUID 39d39482-bb0a-4b0b-b08d-420dc9c2e467
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] DEBUG: message length 118, sending 1 messages
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] DEBUG: Status: 202 Answer: <Sent.>
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [3] DEBUG: Delayed reply - wait for bearerbox
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of 39d39482-bb0a-4b0b-b08d-420dc9c2e467
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Resetting HTTPClient for `192.168.152.1'.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: HTTP: Status line: <HTTP/1.1 200 OK>
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: HTTP: Received response:
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: Octet string at 0x7ff928001190:
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   len:  863
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   size: 1024
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   immutable: 0
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 53 65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 41 53 50 2e 4e 45 54 20   Server: ASP.NET 
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 44 65 76 65 6c 6f 70 6d 65 6e 74 20 53 65 72 76   Development Serv
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 65 72 2f 31 30 2e 30 2e 30 2e 30 0d 0a 44 61 74   er/10.0.0.0..Dat
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 65 3a 20 53 75 6e 2c 20 33 31 20 4d 61 72 20 32   e: Sun, 31 Mar 2
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 30 31 33 20 31 31 3a 32 35 3a 31 37 20 47 4d 54   013 11:25:17 GMT
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 0d 0a 58 2d 41 73 70 4e 65 74 2d 56 65 72 73 69   ..X-AspNet-Versi
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6f 6e 3a 20 34 2e 30 2e 33 30 33 31 39 0d 0a 43   on: 4.0.30319..C
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 70 72   ache-Control: pr
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 69 76 61 74 65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54   ivate..Content-T
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 79 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3b 20   ype: text/html; 
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d 38 0d 0a 43   charset=utf-8..C
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 36   ontent-Length: 6
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 34 36 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20   46..Connection: 
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 43 6c 6f 73 65 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 3c 21 44   Close........<!D
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 20 50 55 42 4c   OCTYPE html PUBL
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 49 43 20 22 2d 2f 2f 57 33 43 2f 2f 44 54 44 20   IC "-//W3C//DTD 
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 58 48 54 4d 4c 20 31 2e 30 20 54 72 61 6e 73 69   XHTML 1.0 Transi
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 74 69 6f 6e 61 6c 2f 2f 45 4e 22 20 22 68 74 74   tional//EN" "htt
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 77 33 2e 6f 72 67 2f 54   p://www.w3.org/T
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 52 2f 78 68 74 6d 6c 31 2f 44 54 44 2f 78 68 74   R/xhtml1/DTD/xht
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6d 6c 31 2d 74 72 61 6e 73 69 74 69 6f 6e 61 6c   ml1-transitional
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 2e 64 74 64 22 3e 0d 0a 0d 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20   .dtd">....<html 
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 78 6d 6c 6e 73 3d 22 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77   xmlns="http://ww
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 77 2e 77 33 2e 6f 72 67 2f 31 39 39 39 2f 78 68   w.w3.org/1999/xh
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 74 6d 6c 22 20 3e 0d 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 74   tml" >..<head><t
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 69 74 6c 65 3e 0d 0a 09 4c 69 76 65 20 53 4d 53   itle>...Live SMS
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 0d 0a 3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 3c 2f 68 65 61 64   ..</title></head
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 3e 0d 0a 0d 0a 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 0d 0a 20 20 20   >....<body>..   
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 20 3c 66 6f 72 6d 20 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 66 6f 72    <form name="for
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6d 31 22 20 6d 65 74 68 6f 64 3d 22 70 6f 73 74   m1" method="post
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 22 20 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 3d 22 52 65 63 65 69 76   " action="Receiv
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 65 53 4d 53 2e 61 73 70 78 3f 74 65 78 74 3d 55   eSMS.aspx?text=U
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 2b 4b 4a 46 32 31 31 31 47 26 61 6d 70 3b 73 65   +KJF2111G&amp;se
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6e 64 65 72 31 3d 25 32 62 32 35 34 37 32 36 37   nder1=%2b1826909
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 30 33 35 33 35 22 20 69 64 3d 22 66 6f 72 6d 31   9574" id="form1
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 22 3e 0d 0a 3c 69 6e 70 75 74 20 74 79 70 65 3d   ">..<input type=
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 22 68 69 64 64 65 6e 22 20 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 5f   "hidden" name="_
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 5f 56 49 45 57 53 54 41 54 45 22 20 69 64 3d 22   _VIEWSTATE" id="
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 5f 5f 56 49 45 57 53 54 41 54 45 22 20 76 61 6c   __VIEWSTATE" val
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 75 65 3d 22 2f 77 45 50 44 77 55 4b 4d 54 45 7a   ue="/wEPDwUKMTEz
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 4d 6a 59 33 4d 7a 51 30 4d 32 52 6b 49 31 41 49   MjY3MzQ0M2RkI1AI
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 59 65 5a 5a 65 6f 63 7a 75 59 6c 37 7a 73 4a 73   YeZZeoczuYl7zsJs
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 78 31 31 74 30 78 7a 4b 36 2b 44 4d 4d 76 4e 71   x11t0xzK6+DMMvNq
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 53 57 73 54 32 50 49 3d 22 20 2f 3e 0d 0a 0d 0a   SWsT2PI=" />....
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3c 43 6f 6e 74              <Cont
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 65 6e 74 54 65 6d 70 6c 61 74 65 3e 0d 0a 20 20   entTemplate>..  
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3c 73                 <s
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 70 61 6e 20 69 64 3d 22 44 61 74 65 53 74 61 6d   pan id="DateStam
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 70 4c 61 62 65 6c 22 3e 4c 49 56 45 20 53 4d 53   pLabel">LIVE SMS
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 3c 2f 73 70 61 6e 3e 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   </span>..       
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 20 20 20 20 20 3c 2f 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 54 65        </ContentTe
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6d 70 6c 61 74 65 3e 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0d 0a   mplate>       ..
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 20 20 20 20 3c 2f 66 6f 72 6d 3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 62       </form>..</b
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG:   data: 6f 64 79 3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a      ody>..</html>..
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [8] DEBUG: Octet string dump ends.
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [5] DEBUG: message length 17, sending 1 messages
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of 2be85cf7-4d1f-4424-96a9-4577ba065623
2013-03-31 14:24:37 [22228] [0] DEBUG: No client - multi-send or ACK to pull-reply
2013-03-31 14:25:37 [22228] [1] DEBUG: Timeout for fd:29 appeares.
2013-03-31 14:25:37 [22228] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7ff94c000a90.
2013-03-31 14:25:37 [22228] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `192.168.152.1'.
```

**Kannel.conf**

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
status-password = foo
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

group = smsc
smsc = at
modemtype = huawei
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
speed = 19200
my-number = 7777777
validityperiod = 167

group = modems 
id = huawei
name = "huawei e160" 
detect-string = "e160"
init-string = "AT+CNMI=1,2,0,1,0" 
speed = 115200

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13013
#global-sender = 13013
global-sender = 1926909539
SMSC: +150555555
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/access.log"

group = sendsms-user
username = kannel
password = kannel
concatenation = true
max-messages = 3

group = sms-service
keyword = default
get-url = "http://localhost/kannel/receivesms.php?sender=%p&text=%b"
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
max-messages = 3
concatenation = true
catch-all = true
```

Answer (score 2):

set this in the service group of the kannel configuration

```
max-messages = 0
```

No matter what the http request returns, the resulting text content wont be to sent out

Answer (score 0):

When Kannel receives a message, it is passed to the URL in the sms-service group, and the response from the URL request is sent back to the user - that is standard behaviour.

In case the response has a *text/html* content type, HTML tags are removed and only text content is sent back, in your case it becomes "Live SMS Live SMS".

If you don't want to send any kind of response, just leave the response empty.

Comment: Am I removing the response in Kannel or in the web application. If its the web app, please guide where I could remove that response as am very green in web applications.

Comment: Try to not output anything from the web application you are passing the message to - in your case, it's the page at the URL "/ProjRequestProcessor/ReceiveSMS.aspx" - you shouldn't have any output there. I think that should solve your problem.